# How to create more than one health check endpoints with Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, health-monitoring

*What I want to do*

- Create two (different) endpoints using Spring Boot Actuator

*My environment*

- Spring Boot 1.4.2
- spring-boot-starter-actuator embedded in Spring Boot 1.4.2

*Detail*

I'm creating a Web app using Spring Boot and will need to create two separated endpoints: one for just checking application health including the app's DB connection and so on (This will be realized by the default behavior of "/health") and the other for just checking if the app is ready for accepting HTTP requests (say "/httpcheck").

To implement health check feature, I guess it's the fastest way to use Spring Boot Actuator (by default, /health is mapped to health check endpoint).
I also understand we can configure this endpoint by extending AbstractHealthIndicator (so that it will include DB health check).

But as far as I could see, I could not find a way to create more than one endpoints to do different health checks.
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.
Actually, I dealt with this problem by implementing a new endpoint (/httpcheck) to simply check if its HTTP stack works well or not.

**HttpCheckEndpoint.java**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "endpoints.httpcheck") // Specifies the prefix on application.yml
public class HttpCheckEndpoint extends AbstractMvcEndpoint {

    public HttpCheckEndpoint() {
        super("/httpcheck", false);
    }

    /**
     * Check if simply the app can connect to their own HTTP stack and return 200 OK.
     * <ul>
     * <li>Method: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS</li>
     * <li>Endpoint: "/httpcheck"</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> checkHttpConnecton() {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"status\": \"UP\"}", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
endpoints:
  enabled: false # Default enabled/disabled on endpoints on Spring Boot Actuator
  health: # Health check (already prepared in Spring Boot Actuator)
    enabled: true
  httpcheck: # Simple HTTP connection check (newly created by myself)
    enabled: true
```

I've confirmed it worked well, although not sure if it's the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. You can use **Jolokia** end points in your Spring-boot application and get it registered with o.s.b.a.e.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter along with your Actuator Plugins.
2. `<dependency>
           <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
           <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.2</version>
   </dependency>`
3. Jolokia Configurations in application.properties

   ```
        jolokia.config.debug=true
        endpoints.jolokia.enabled=true
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for late.
I've confirmed it worked.
In my understanding, jolokia monitors the app via JMX, right?

Comment: Yes, that provides you more flexible way of doing your health check without even any special coding for your scenario. You can add this as a dependency in your pom file and the few entries in application.properties /application. yml file.